# php/ xml Test is xml contains element

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

can you test if an xml file has a specific element. I tried this below:

```
    $restrict = ($xml_content->xpath('//app:control//yt:state'));
$name = $restrict[0][0];

$restrictTest = $name->attributes();

if ($restrictTest == "restricted"){
    $_SESSION['array']['restricted'] = 1;
}
```

but it displays this error:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: Undefined namespace prefix in C:\xampp\htdocs\ytm\resources\func.php on line 178
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\ytm\resources\func.php on line 178
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ytm\resources\func.php on line 181

Comment: Your first problem is the namespace you're passing on line 178. I'm guessing that `//appLcontrol//yt:state` is not defined as a namespace.

Comment: Can you show how your `$xml_content` is created? Is this SimpleXML for example? It also might help to show example section of XML that you are trying to use xpath on.

Comment: i create $xml_content like this:


 $xmlstr  = file_get_contents($xml);
 $xml_content = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

Comment: Well, I can tell you what the error means, but without any example XML, can only guess why it is happening. Either "app:" or "yt:" (or possibly both) is not known to the XPath processor in SimpleXML. [getDocNamespaces](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getdocnamespaces.php) and [registerXPathNamespace](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) may be relevant.